# procedure of force fixed EMAC(ethernet media access controller) and phy speed and duplex in SW&HW

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, hardware, ethernet, ethernet-phy

After learning AN(auto-negotiation) of etherner PHY,i've known that the basic procedure is
1.phy AN with each other(provided local phy and link-partner both support AN)
2.phy inform MAC AN complete and MAC inform SW
3.SW driver configure MAC the same operation mode as PHY

However, if user of ethernet device want to force fixed speed and duplex of MAC and PHY while net running normally,what's the detail procedure of it? In my opinion, i think may be the procedure is :
1.SW stop MAC after ensure tx fifo&rx fifo of EMAC are empty and stop EMAC by write EMAC tx/rx transmision register
2.SW disable PHY AN by register writing and set fixed speed and duplex of PHY
3.SW config EMAC speed and duplex
4.Ensure clock of EMAC macthes EMAC mode,and restart EMAC(restart DMA,MTL,MAC...)

Can someone who is familiar with linux ethernet driver answer me that if my understanding about this procedure is correct or not? Thank you very much !!

I searched a lot on internet about this question but the results are always about AN use examples.It seems that there are no someone who could introduce this HW&SW procedure clearly...